# Reduction/Elimination of some terms in DSolve output

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a specific problem regarding differential equation output:

[image]

As you may see, the first input is my function.

```
DSolve[D[w[x], {x, 4}] + k^2*D[w[x], {x, 2}] == 0, w[x], x]
```

In there any way to obtain the output as shown in `w0[x_]` in the third line?

```
w0[x_] = A1*Cos[k*x] + B1*Sin[k*x] + C1*x + D1
```

I would like to get rid of some signs and constants from `Out[1]` equation which are not necessary for me: for instance, I'd like `-c1/k^2` to become the unknown constant `A1`. I would like to get rid of other constants in a similar manner.

Would it also be possible to assign all of this as a simple equation as in `In[2]`?

I am rather new at Mathematica, so an easy solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may replace k^-2 in the solution by 1 like:

```
sol = DSolve[D[w[x], {x, 4}] + k^2*D[w[x], {x, 2}] == 0, w[x], x][[1]];
sol = sol /. {k^-2 -> 1}

{w[x] -> C[3] + x  C[4] - C[1] Cos[k x] - C[2] Sin[k x]}
```

With this you can define w0 like:

```
w0[x_] = w[x] /. sol

C[3] + x  C[4] - C[1] Cos[k x] - C[2] Sin[k x]
```

**Addendum**

To get positive parameters in the form "Ai" :

```
sol = DSolve[D[w[x], {x, 4}] + k^2*D[w[x], {x, 2}] == 0, w[x], x][[1]];
sol = sol /. k^-2 -> 1 /. -C[i_] :> C[i] /. 
   C[i_] :> Symbol["A" <> ToString[i]];

t = w0[x_] = w[x] /. sol

A3 + A4 x + A1 Cos[k x] + A2 Sin[k x]
```

Comment: Thank you, but still how about renaming constants C[1] into A1 etc.?

Comment: @Krzysztof  add `GeneratedParameters->A` to your `DSolve` command  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Ozv.png)

Comment: @Nasser okay, thanks, however I have specified my question wrong previously about renaming constatns. 
I would like to get positive `A1` variable instead of `-C[1]/k^2` any solution to that and `A2` as a `-C[2]/k^2`, then `A3` for `C[3]`. All variables without square brackets. Is it possible?

Comment: Look at the "Addendum" in my answer.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you so much! It resolves all my problems! :)